NextJS Reusable API Fetch Function
I am wondering where I may be going wrong.
I am looking to create one function that can be repeatedly used to call from an API.
I have the below code, however I can't get past a 'fetch' error?
useFetcher.js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function Fetch( query, api, apikey ) {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    var url = query;

    if( api ) { apikey = '&apikey=' + apikey; url = query + apikey; }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch( url )
            .then(( res ) => res.json() )
            .then(( data ) => {
                setData( data )
                setLoading( false )
            }
        )
    }, []);

    if( isLoading ) { return ( <p>Loading...</p> ) }
    if( !data ) { return ( <p>No profile data</p> ) }

    console.log( data );

    return { data }

}

Inside a page, I have applied the following code but seem to get an error every time. What might I be doing wrong?
page.tsx
var authorId = '5';
var authorLink = "https://example.com/api/v1/author/" + authorId;
var author = Fetch( authorLink, true, 'ApiKeyHere' );

I am using Readarr API to get the information from the supplied author id.
What I expect to see is something below:
Readarr API
{
  "authorMetadataId": 3,
  "status": "continuing",
  "ended": false,
  "authorName": "Sarah J. Maas",
  "authorNameLastFirst": "Maas, Sarah J.",
  "foreignAuthorId": "3433047",
  "titleSlug": "3433047",
  "overview": "Sarah J. Maas is the #1 New York Times and internationally bestselling author of the Crescent City, A Court of Thorns and Roses, and the Throne of Glass series. Her books have sold more than twelve million copies and are published in thirty-seven languages. A New York native, Sarah lives in Philadelphia with her husband, son, and dog. To find out more, visit sarahjmaas.com or follow @therealsjmaas on Instagram.",
  "links": [
    {
      "url": "http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/3433047.Sarah_J_Maas",
      "name": "Goodreads"
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "url": "/MediaCover/5/poster.jpg?lastWrite=637177342560000000",
      "coverType": "poster",
      "extension": ".jpg"
    }
  ],
  "path": "/data",
  "qualityProfileId": 1,
  "metadataProfileId": 1,
  "monitored": true,
  "monitorNewItems": "all",
  "rootFolderPath": "/data",
  "genres": [],
  "cleanName": "sarahjmaas",
  "sortName": "sarah j. maas",
  "sortNameLastFirst": "maas, sarah j.",
  "tags": [],
  "added": "2024-02-09T09:10:50Z",
  "ratings": {
    "votes": 11962351,
    "value": 4.36,
    "popularity": 52155850.36000001
  },
  "statistics": {
    "bookFileCount": 17,
    "bookCount": 26,
    "availableBookCount": 17,
    "totalBookCount": 26,
    "sizeOnDisk": 22554283,
    "percentOfBooks": 65.38461538461539
  },
  "id": 5
}

Is the issue that I cant use useEffect and instead need something like THIS?

I don’t want to discourage you from writing your own, but this is what libraries are for. useSWR or tanstack query have your reusable fetch function and a thousand more directly related features that you would never think of to write yourself. Learn how to use high quality, well maintained libraries, don’t roll your own.

I did manage to play around with some more code and get a reply as a Promise, however I did try the useSWR library and it worked a charm! Made it a lot easier to understand also! Thank you for your suggestion :)
